No PRT with Certificate Based Authentication in Microsoft Entra Hybrid Setup
I have Entra Hybrid setup where on prem AD is connected to Azure AD using AzureAD Connect.
From a domain joined computer, if user logs in with username/password, PRT is available and user can open office portal without entering credentials.
But if user logs in with passwordless solution(certificate based authentication), PRT is not available and while opening office portal, user is asked to enter credentials.
dsregcmd /status output

AzureADPrt : NO
Server Error Code :    invalid_client
Server Error
Description : AADSTS50017 : Validation of    given certificate for
certificate based authentication failed.

I have uploaded CA certificate in Azure portal certificate authorities page and enabled CBA.
Event viewer AAD Operational log shows the same error AADSTS50017.
Analytic log with event ID 1007 has
AadCloudAPPlugin GetToken Stop
Status: 0xC000006D
I have tried sample V2 credential provider with username/password and PRT is issued. So, third party CP may not be a problem for issuing PRT.
Thanks for the help.

The error AADSTS50017 suggests a certificate validation failure, likely due to a misconfigured certificate authority or missing intermediate certificates in Azure AD. Ensure that the certificate chain is correctly uploaded to Azure AD and that your device is properly hybrid-joined and registered with Azure AD.
